# Add an item to a list of piped items

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I need to add items to a list of items. I am not sure if these are the correct terms.

Example:

Suppose I am inside a directory with 2 files, "a" and "b". If I pipe `ls` to `less` my list will have two items, "a" and "b": `ls | less`

I want to pipe ls to less, but before reach the less command I want an item added to the list. e.g:

`ls -->unknow shell feature<-- less`

And the content listed by less would be "a", "b" and "c" (file "c" doesn't exist)

Is it possible?

Comment: I understand your question up to the point where you mention `c`.  What is `c`?

Comment: @Kusalananda "c" is just a string to be appended to the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest would be

`(ls;echo c) | less`

Comment: You can save a subprocess with `{ ls; echo c; } | less`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to achieve that. Here are two examples:

**Using pipes twice:**

```bash
ls | (cat;echo fuzz) | less
```

**Using input redirection:**

```bash
ls | less < <(cat;echo fuzz)
```

In **zsh shells** you can also use:

```bash
ls | <<<"buzz" | less
#or
ls | < <(echo fuzz) | less
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to list each visible name in the current directory, add `c` to the end of the list, and view the result in `less`:

```bash
printf '%s\n' * c | less
```

---

The rest of this answer deals with creating a separate list of filenames, adding something to that list and then either using it as arguments to `less`, or viewing the list in `less` (depending on how we interpret the question).

---

You may use an array to store the names of all visible files in the current directory:

```bash
names=( * )
```

You may add things to the end of an array:

```bash
names+=( c )
```

... or in one go when you set the array's initial values:

```bash
names=( * c )
```

You may use the elements in the array as arguments to `less`:

```bash
less -- "${names[@]}"
```

(The `--` is used to ensure that `less` interprets the arguments as filenames and not as options.  This matters if any filename starts with a dash.)

Or, you may list the elements of the `names` array using `less`:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}" | less
```

Doing the same things but using the list of positional parameters in place of a named array:

```bash
set -- *
set -- "$@" c
```

... or,

```
set -- * c
```

Then calling `less` with these elements as arguments:

```bash
less -- "$@"
```

Or, listing the positional parameters with `less`:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$@" | less
```

Note that the quoting in all the above commands is important.  Quoting `"$@"` and `"${names[@]}"` like this ensures that the shell expands them as lists of individually quoted elements.